# Insert problem in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, insert, sqlite

Actually I am not sure there is a problem but, I have some data and I want to insert it to database.

Code seems to works well, every statement works, there are no errors shown but I cant see the data in database. It doesn't insert the data to database but in code it is shown as data is inserted.

Is there a setting related with database? I am using Sqlite Firefox Add-on. 
When selecting records there are no problems. I checked the .sqlite file's permissions but it is setted to read & write.

Sorry, I forgot to add code snippet;

```
   NSString *stmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO t_exam_applies(user_id,exam_id, apply_correct, apply_wrong, apply_empty, apply_start, apply_end) VALUES(%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d)", 0,exam_id,0,0,0,0,0];
        [stmt UTF8String];
        const char *sql=(const char *) [stmt UTF8String];
        //const char *sql= "INSERT INTO t_exam_applies(user_id,exam_id, apply_correct, apply_wrong, apply_empty, apply_start, apply_end) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"SQLITE statement executed");
    else 
        NSLog(@"ERROR!!");

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Comment: Have you got uncommitted transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is tagged for iPhone dev I would recommend using an objective c wrapper for sqlite like FMDB.  FMDB is very lightweight and widely used (check it out on github: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/) and will simplify this whole process for you.

Here is an example of a simple insert with FMDB:

```
self.db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:fullPath];

 if (![db open]) {
     NSLog(@"DB Open Failed");
     return NO;
 }

[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO TestTable (id, value) VALUES (?,?)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"SomeString"];

[db close];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are messaging nil when adding the data (assuming you use Obj-C)? That's not an error, but it also doesn't do anything. More info or code snippet needed for more specific answer.